# Frequency calculation using Quantum Espresso

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, quantum-espresso, gaussian, materials-studio

I want to calculate the frequency using quantum espresso. How can I get the input file of frequency calculation using QE?

```
&control
    calculation = 'vc-relax'
    restart_mode = 'from_scratch'
    prefix = 'your_prefix'
    tstress = .true.
    tprnfor = .true.
    pseudo_dir = 'path/to/pseudopotentials'
    outdir = './'
/

&system
    ibrav = 1
    celldm(1) = 10.0
    nat = 3
    ntyp = 2
    ecutwfc = 30.0
    ecutrho = 300.0
    occupations = 'smearing'
    smearing = 'mp'
    degauss = 0.02
/

&electrons
    conv_thr = 1.0e-8
/

&ions
    ion_dynamics = 'bfgs'
/

&cell
    cell_dynamics = 'bfgs'
/

ATOMIC_SPECIES
   element1  12.01  element1.pbe-rrkjus.UPF
   element2  1.01   element2.pbe-rrkjus.UPF

ATOMIC_POSITIONS crystal
   element1  0.0  0.0  0.0
   element1  0.25 0.25 0.25
   element2  0.5  0.5  0.5

K_POINTS automatic
   4 4 4 1 1 1
```

Comment: What do you mean by *frequency*? Do you mean the vibrational properties calculation such as phonon band structure? Also, since you are looking for QE specific solution, the vasp, gaussian and materials-studio tags are irrelevant here. The template QE code you provided seems unnecessary in this question.

Comment: I want to calculate vibrational frequency which is used to calculate Gibbs free energy.